# Python parsing ini file with global scope/properties

Tags: python, ini

Sample ini file that I want to parse and change.

```
global_key = global_value
.include other_file.ini

[section]
key = value
```

Is there a way to parse and augment this with Python? I know usually [ConfigParser](https://docs.python.org/3/library/configparser.html#) is recommended for ini files, I didn't find any way to parse a file with global scope.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`.ini` file always [requires section headers](https://docs.python.org/3/library/configparser.html#supported-ini-file-structure).

In this case you can create a custom section header and use `allow_no_value=True` to parse with `ConfigParser` class. [The `allow_no_value=False`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/configparser.html#customizing-parser-behaviour) says the parser to parse the settings without values.

```
>>> string = """
... global_key = global_value
... .include other_file.ini
... 
... [section]
... key = value
... """
>>> 
>>> from configparser import ConfigParser
>>> 
>>> parser = ConfigParser(allow_no_value=True)
>>> parser.read_string("[GLOBAL]\n" + string)
>>> for key in parser["GLOBAL"]:
...     print(key)
... 
global_key
.include other_file.ini
```